# Creating multiples variables for syms

Tags: matlab

I want to create many variables such as x1, x2, x3 to use beside syms so it will look something like this:

syms x1 x2 x3 x4 ... x50 x51....xn

n is the number of variables I need.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = sym('x', [n 1]);
```

This will create n symbolic variables i.e. `x1, x2, x3 ......, xn` and you can access them using `x(1), x(2), x(3)....., x(n)` respectively

For example with n=4, you'll get these results:

```
>> x

x =

 x1
 x2
 x3
 x4

>> x(1)

ans =

x1

>> x(3)

ans =

x3
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! Good one

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can use this vector when solving linear equations using linsolve? 
So that it becomes like this:

syms x (instead of)
syms x1 x2 x3 x4....xn (where I have to list them all out)